# Modal popup extender using asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, popup

I am using modal popup extender in asp.net for displaying modal popup. When i click on target button modal popup display successfully and if click cancel button it will close successfully also. But my problem is when i click browser back button again modal popup button will display but i do not want to display modal popup please bring me out of this problem.Code is below

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CssClass="btndesign" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalpopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="Button1" CancelControlID="cancel" PopupControlID="panel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" Style="background: linear-gradient(to top,#ffffff 0%, #f1f6f9  50%); width: 31%; display: none">
        <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" Text="X" Style="float: right; margin-top: 9px; margin-right: 3px; background: #ef5350; border-color: #ef5350; color: #fff; font-size: 11px; padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 3px;" />
        <h4 style="text-align: left; background-color: #fff; padding: 2%; margin-top: 5px;">Business</h4>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>EIN</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editein" runat="server" MaxLength="9" ValidationGroup="editgroup" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="editfteein" runat="server" TargetControlID="editein" ValidChars="0123456789"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="editrequired" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="editein" ErrorMessage="Please Enter EIN Number" Display="None" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editvce" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrequired" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="editexpression" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="editein" ErrorMessage="EIN Must be of 9 digits" ValidationExpression="^\d{9}$" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editexpvce" runat="server" TargetControlID="editexpression" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Business Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editname" runat="server" MaxLength="50" ValidationGroup="editgroup" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="editftebusinessname" runat="server" TargetControlID="editname" ValidChars="&#()' -" FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="editrfvbusinessname" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="editname" ErrorMessage="Please enter business name here" Display="None" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editvcebusinessname" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrfvbusinessname" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="editrevbusninessname" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="editname" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid business name" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9#&()'\s-]{4,75}$" Display="None" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editvcerevbusninessname" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrevbusninessname" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="changeaddress" runat="server" Text="Address changed from last filing" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address Line</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editaddress" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="editfteaddress" runat="server" TargetControlID="editaddress" FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=" -/"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="editrfvaddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="editaddress" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter address" Display="None" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editvceaddress" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrfvaddress" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="editrevaddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="editaddress" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid address" Display="None" ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z0-9]( ?[A-Za-z0-9\-/])*" ValidationGroup="editgroup"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editrevvceaddress" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrevaddress" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Address Line 2</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editadd2" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="editfteaddress2" runat="server" TargetControlID="editadd2" FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=" -/"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="editcity" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="editftecity" runat="server" TargetControlID="editcity" FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=" "></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="editrfvcity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="editcity" ErrorMessage="Please enter city name" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="editgroup" Display="None"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="editvcecity" runat="server" TargetControlID="editrfvcity" PopupPosition="Right"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>State</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtState" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails"
                            Visible="false" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteState" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtState"
                            FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Custom" ValidChars=" ">
                        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvState" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtState"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your state here" Display="None" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_rfvState" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right"
                            TargetControlID="rfvState" HighlightCssClass="errorField">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revState" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtState"
                            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid state name"
                            ValidationExpression="[A-Z,a-z ]{1,50}" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails"> 
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_revState" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right"
                            TargetControlID="revState" HighlightCssClass="errorField">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Style="width: 300px">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStateddl" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlState"
                            ErrorMessage="Please select state" InitialValue="0" Display="None" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_rfvStateddl" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right"
                            TargetControlID="rfvStateddl" HighlightCssClass="errorField">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Country</td>
                    <td>

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="editcontry" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" Style="margin-bottom: 10px; width: 300px"
                            AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="United States of America" Value="US"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Canada" Value="CA"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mexico" Value="MX"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Zip</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtZip" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails"
                            MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteZip" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtZip"
                            FilterType="LowercaseLetters,UppercaseLetters,Numbers,Custom" ValidChars=" "
                            Enabled="false">
                        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fteZipUS" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtZip"
                            FilterType="Numbers" Enabled="false">
                        </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvZip" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZip"
                            ErrorMessage="Please enter your zip code here" Display="None" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_rfvZip" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right"
                            TargetControlID="rfvZip" HighlightCssClass="errorField">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revZip" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtZip"
                            SetFocusOnError="True" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid zip code"
                            ValidationExpression="[0-9]{5}(([0-9]{4}))?" ValidationGroup="BusinessDetails"> 
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_revZip" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right"
                            TargetControlID="revZip" HighlightCssClass="errorField">
                        </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div style="background: #5f9fa1; padding: 2%;">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="updatemaster" runat="server" Text="Also Update Master Business Info" required=""></asp:CheckBox>
            <asp:Button ID="updateprocess" runat="server" Text="Update & Process" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this line in your page load.

```
modalpopup.Hide();
```

Comment: I tried but not working .........The problem is that  code behind won't even run when the back button is clicked, the page is loaded from cache. If the last page load (postback or not) had a popup, it will show that popup again

Answer (score 0):

You can put `this.Hide()` or in the click function of cancel button then `modalpopup.Hide()`